# How to join a string object with a tensor (tf.string) like pathlib.Path with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to join two strings objects, but one of them is a tensor, so I should use `tf.*` functions, thus pathlib.Path is not available.

How may I reproduce this:

```py
>>> a = "train"
>>> b = "a.JPEG"
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> (Path(a) / Path(b)).as_posix()
'train/a.JPEG'
```

if `b` is a tensor (tf.string)? (not knowing if `a` ends with a "/" or not)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @M.Innat I want to do what Path() does but with Tensors